# ODBC SQL Server Driver - Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, vba, stored-procedures, odbc, parameter-passing

I am using MS Access VBA to call a stored procedure with paramters passed from Access. I am having issues passing my date variables to the SQL Server Stored procedure:

VBA:

```
Dim zsql, asql, bsql, gsql As String
Dim searchDeal, searchReviewed As String
Dim searchDate, searchFile As Date
Dim searchType As String
Dim user As String
Dim qdfNew As DAO.QueryDef

Dim myRecordset6 As DAO.Recordset
Dim myDatabase6 As DAO.Database
Dim mycheckRs As DAO.Recordset

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

searchDeal = Me.cboDeal.Value
searchDate = Me.cboStDate.Value
searchFile = Me.cboFile.Value
user = GetUser()

 Dim dbconn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim param As New ADODB.Parameter

'' Connect to Data Source - Securities DB - SQL Server
Set dbconn = New ADODB.Connection
dbconn.ConnectionString = "driver=SQL Server;server=R7SQL1;database=SecuritiesDB;trusted_connection=YES"
dbconn.Open dbconn.ConnectionString
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = dbconn

'' Set CommandText equal to the stored procedure name (spStatementCheck)
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "spAppendActivity"
''cmd.NamedParameters = True 'paramStatementCheck'
cmd.Parameters.Append _
    cmd.CreateParameter("@SPstrNGN", adVarChar, adParamInput, 25, searchDeal)
cmd.Parameters.Append _
    cmd.CreateParameter("@SPuser", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, user)
cmd.Parameters.Append _
    cmd.CreateParameter("@SPdDateActivity", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, 10, searchDate) <--ISSUE
cmd.Parameters.Append _
    cmd.CreateParameter("@SPdDateFile", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, 10, searchFile) <--ISSUE
--Date format that I am passing should be MM/DD/YYYY

rs.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic
rs.Open cmd
```

SQL:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAppendActivity]
        @SPsearchDeal as nvarchar(25),
        @SPsearchDate as datetime,
        @SPsearchFile as datetime,
        @SPuser as nvarchar(100)    
    AS

        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        -- Insert statements for procedure here
    delete from tbl_Activity_Losses; 

INSERT into tbl_Activity_Losses ([Date], NGN_Short, FileDate)
Select [Date], NGN_Short, Filedate
from tbl_Master_Rec
where tbl_Master_Rec.[Date] = @SPsearchDate <--Conversion Issue
and tbl_Master_Rec.FileDate = @SPsearchFile <--Conversion Issue
and  tbl_Master_Rec.NGN_Short like '%' +  @SPsearchDeal + '%'
```

I get the following error message when the Date is passed using the adDBTimeStamp "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver] Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

I have also tried passing the date as adDBDate and get the error "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver] Optional Feature Not Implemented. "

Please let me know if you need more information on the issue I am having

Comment: I am still having issues with the above code. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that you will need to construct the datetime string in this format:

**adDBDate**
Indicates a date value (yyyymmdd) (DBTYPE_DBDATE).

**adDBTimeStamp**
Indicates a date/time stamp (yyyymmddhhmmss plus a fraction in billionths) (DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP).

[adDBDate and adDBTimeStamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675318%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Will I need to dim the date variables as string? Or will I need to create the datetime string in the stored procedure?

Comment: @user2989011  you will need to construct the datetime string before pass it in the parameter creation in VBA.

Comment: would it be something similar to this:'cmd.Parameters.Append _
    cmd.CreateParameter("@SPdDateFile", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, 10, format(searchFile,"MM/DD/YYYY"))'

Comment: format(searchFile,"yyyymmdd") as specified in link included earlier.

Comment: When I update this code, I get an error "Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation." Do you know why this error would be occuring?  'cmd.Parameters.Append _
    cmd.CreateParameter("@SPdDateFile", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, 0, Format(searchFile, "yyyymmdd"))'